# How do I use Android View Binding in a library module?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I think I know the answer to this, but...

I enabled View Binding in a library module. Fine. I then take that .AAR and use it in another app, where I've *not* enabled View Binding. When I run that app and start an Activity from the library, I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/viewbinding/ViewBinding;
```

If I then enable view binding in the app, everything works fine. It seems like I should be able to use view binding in a library without having to also enable it in the app.

Is the necessary class getting Proguarded away, perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

I figured that when I enabled View Binding, it was probably adding a library that I wasn't seeing. I discovered I could add

```
implementation 'androidx.databinding:viewbinding:7.1.2'
```

*instead* of enabling View Binding, which solved my problem.

Comment: I had the same issue with .aar file. Adding this dependency fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image: check this androidx/viewbinding/ViewBinding has in apk]

check this androidx/viewbinding/ViewBinding has in apk